# How can I `DBI->connect()` to MySQL when Perl erroneously says: "utf8mb4 is not a compiled character set"?

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

An [old Perl script](https://github.com/jzawodn/mytop) I've come to rely on ([mytop](https://github.com/jzawodn/mytop)) is tripping on MySQL character sets.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $config{user}, $config{pass}, { PrintError => 0 });
```

Returns:

```
Character set 'utf8mb4' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

And the `$DBI::errstr`:

```
Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/)
```

And yet
`SHOW CHARSET;` reveals both `utf8` and `utf8mb4`, while `mysql/charsets/Index.xml` only shows `utf8`.

One solution I found was to edit `mysql/charsets/Index.xml` to change:

`<charset name="utf8">` to `<charset name="utf8mb4">`

This actually works for the perl script, but unfortunately removes `utf8` from `SHOW CHARSET;` and disables certain MySQL clients (like MySQL Workbench and PHPMyAdmin).

How else can I work around this error?

Obviously `utf8mb4` is already compiled and available, despite the error. I tried adding a `utf8mb4` alias to the `<charset name="utf8">` in the `Index.xml` but that didn't work either.

---

Here is the relevant db connection code I'm trying to move past:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $config{user}, $config{pass},
                       { PrintError => 0 });

if (not ref $dbh)
{
    die $DBI::errstr;
}
```

---

Here are the relevant `my.cnf` settings:

```
[client]
default-character-set           = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set           = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake  = FALSE
character_set_server            = utf8mb4
collation_server                = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem here is entirely with `libmysqlclient` and your mysql config, and not perl, DBI, or your script.

Comment: @hobbs any direction on what I may need to look for there?

Comment: @hobbs, I changed my `default-character-set = utf8` for `[client]` and `[mysql]`, but left `[mysqld]` as above in my `my.cnf`. This solved the issue for my perl script. And I still can support emojis (imports working). Can you tell me why this worked? And any danger that might result?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by editing my `my.cnf` as follows. But I'm not sure if I've caused not-yet-known troubles.

`my.cnf`

```
[client]
default-character-set           = utf8                   # changed from utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set           = utf8                   # changed from utf8mb4

[mysqld]                                                 # left [mysqld] as is
character-set-client-handshake  = FALSE
character_set_server            = utf8mb4
collation_server                = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this causes issues with connecting clients that want to write unicode that is only supported by utf8mb4 (MBP blocks)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error when using xtrabackup. I added this code in my.cnf and it solves the problem:

```
[xtrabackup]
default-character-set           = utf8
```

I leave [client] and [mysql] section in my.cnf to utf8mb4 while connecting to other server.

Since xtrabackup does binary backup, I think set utf8 to xtrabackup only will not make any side effects to the backup data.

I don't know if there is a solution for connecting using perl. May be you should find a way for your script to read my.cnf and create a custom section for the script to read the custom "default-character-set"

EDIT:

I've searched and found a solution, check this if this works.
Set this before create your connection:

```
mysql_read_default_group = "perl"
```

and create a custom section in your my.cnf

```
[perl]
default-character-set           = utf8
```